Time Stories Missing cards Prophecy of the dragon & The Marcy case
I’m looking for picture of 2 missing cards in two different time stories extansions :

card number 26, element 19 (the one we had to kept for other missions) in PoD
card 68 (Church B) in The Marcy case.

Could you help me?

I dont really think this deserves a downvote. There are older questions already asking for missing cards and unlike a normal card game, a missing card can be game critical and it is impossible to guess what it contains. Some cards are more important than others but before actually playing it, you simply don't know

I just have the german version of PoD, but here are the cards anyway.





Thank you so much!
Could you take a picture of the other side of the PoD card as well?

@Lear sure, no problem

Thank you so much!!

To possibly make things easier, here's the English version of Item 19


Interesting is, that the part for "Keep this object for future adventures. You never know" is missing. And even the flavortext is different. The german text is talking about milk colored area, the englisch one uses blue transluscent

@Zibelas perhaps I have an older version of the case? I've had these games for years, unfortunately never had a stable group to play a legacy game like them. Had to open the deck wrapping to take the picture.

I had to open the marcy case, had no time yet to play it. I must say, time stories does not take that long for a game, you can finish an extension in around 3h even with people who do not know it yet. And even though it is a legacy game, you can play the extensions as well in any order without knowledge of the others. There is an overall story, but you can enjoy just the extensions itself

@Zibelas it's less the time commitment of each case, and more the commitment of the right sized, steady play group to run through all 5 that I own

I know that feeling, currently trying to get a stable group for Arkham Horror. I played a few of the scenarios with only my wife. It turned out quite well even if we only controlled one investigator each.

Thanks a lot @andrew !
